# Can docker read credentials from environment variable?

Tags: docker

My docker registry can generate temporary credentials. I want to use that in my CI server instead of a bot account. I wonder if I can have something like `auth: ${DOCKER_CRED_ENV_VARIABLE}` in ~/.docker/config.json. I know both maven and npm support this, but did not find anything similar in docker.

Comment: You can use the `DOCKER_CRED_ENV_VARIABLE` directly in your Dockerfile, if that fits your approach.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. Read this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/